# Change text into a button doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I write the next code:

```
<span id="post">search by id</span>


$("#post").click(function () {
    var input = $("<input type='text' id='input_find_by_id'><button type='button' id='button_search_by_id'>Click Me!</button>");
    $(this).replaceWith(input);
    setTimeout(function() {change();},1250);
});


function change() {
    var input = $("<span id='post'><u>search by id</u></span>");
    $("#input_find_by_id").replaceWith(input);
    $("#button_search_by_id").remove();
    //input.select();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/APjyy/2/

when I press "search by id", it is changed into a button and then, after 1 moment, it returns to be "search by id".

**But** when I try to press it again, nothing is happen. why don't I get again the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace the original span with another content, you effectively remove the element from the DOM - along with any events attached to it.  When you then add your span again (in `change` function), it's a newly created element, which doesn't have any event handlers attached to it - you would need to attached the event handler again.

The alternative to solve this would be to use [jQuery `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to attach "live" event handlers:

```
$(document).on('click', '#post', function () {
    ...
});
```

In addition, since you're only calling one function with no arguments in your `setTimeout`, you can simplify it to

```
setTimeout(change, 1250);
```

Answer (score 1):

You no longer have an event handler on your newly created elements.

Change your event handler to be on the document and to be handled if a specific selector is matched. This way your event handler would be fired for every new element that meets the selector criteria:

```
$(document).on('click', '#post', function () {
    var input = $("<input type='text' id='input_find_by_id'><button type='button' id='button_search_by_id'>Click Me!</button>");
    $(this).replaceWith(input);
    setTimeout(function() {change();},1250);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

after you replace the searchbox with the "post" span, you are not rebinding the click event to that span..

example here, even if I think is not very beautufil: http://jsfiddle.net/APjyy/5/

```
function change() {
    var input = $("<span id='post'><u>search by id</u></span>");

    $("#input_find_by_id").replaceWith(input);
    $("#button_search_by_id").remove();
    //input.select();

    $("#post").click(function () {
        var input = $("<input type='text' id='input_find_by_id'><button type='button' id='button_search_by_id'>Click Me!</button>");
        $(this).replaceWith(input);
        setTimeout(function () {
            change();
        }, 1250);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by hiding the text and un hiding the already present but hidden button

Answer (score 1):

USe this: You are adding "post" id elements under change() function:

```
$("#post").click(function () {
        var input = $("<input type='text' id='input_find_by_id'><button type='button' id='button_search_by_id'>Click Me!</button>");
        $(this).replaceWith(input);
        //setTimeout(function() {change();},1250);
    });


    function change() {
        var input = $("<u>search by id</u>");
        $("#input_find_by_id").replaceWith(input);
        $("#button_search_by_id").remove();
        //input.select();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/APjyy/6/

When you are clicking "`search by id`" for the first time, you have to `rebind` it to `"#post"`. Because, you are removing the element from `DOM` and hence the event listener is also getting removed. When you are re adding the element, `jQuery` does not know anything about it, hence the listener does not works.

You need to use event `delegation`.

```
$("body").on('click', '#post' , function () {

});
```

See the documentation here. http://api.jquery.com/on/